# Lazarus - Erro ao executar programa com fpCEF

Tags: lazarus, object-pascal, chromium

Estou tendo problemas ao seguir [esse simples tutorial](http://lazplanet.blogspot.com.br/2015/09/create-web-browser-in-3-minutes-using.html) de construção de um WebBrowser usando fpCEF.

Baixei a última versão do fpCEF [direto do Github](https://github.com/dliw/fpCEF3/releases/tag/v3.2526), para a versão 3.2526 do CEF, e os binários dele eu peguei do [CEFBuilds](https://cefbuilds.com/#branch_2526) (único lugar confiável que eu encontrei que tinha essa build já antiga).

Bom, estou usando o `Lazarus 1.6 r51630 FPC 3.0.0 x86_64-win64-win32/win64`, estou usando o Windows 10 x64.

Ao tentar executar o programa usando os binários x64 (os colocando conforme o tutorial passou) o programa não abre e aparece a janela de depuração com as seguintes linhas:

```
00007FFA02F74163 4883c428                 add    $0x28,%rsp
```

E caso eu tente executar diretamente o exe criado recebo o erro `External exception 80000003`

Caso eu tente executar com os binários x86 (32 bits), recebo o erro `OS Code 193`

Já estou quase apelando a usar um controle ActiveX pra carregar o IE com tantos erros com o CEF.

O que posso fazer pra fazer o fpCEF rodar?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1- Baixe o FPCEF, instale o FPCEF no seu Lazarus como já deve ter feito

2- Baixe a versão correspondente dos binários do cef, se por ex for 2543 o seu fpcef, tem que usar os binários da CEF 2543, e assim por diante e descomprima criando a pasta cef_binary onde terá a pasta **Release** e **Resources**.

3- Dentro da pasta do seu projeto copie **somente os arquivos** da pasta **Release** na raiz do seu projeto. (como já deve ter feito)

4- Copie a pasta Resources **inteira** para raiz do seu projeto ficando a pasta Resources criada dentro da raiz do projeto.   (como já deve ter feito)

5- **E agora o segredo do seu erro:** Faça uma cópia extra do arquivo icudtl.dat que esta agora dentro da pasta Resources do projeto para dentro da pasta raiz do projeto também.

6- E finalmente no seu FormCreate garanta que o aplicativo esta achando o **caminho completo** dos binários do framework, pois no tutorial ele usou o caminho parcial e o FPCEF só funciona assim nas versões antigas.

```
myworkdir := GetCurrentDir;
CefResourcesDirPath:=concat(myworkdir, '\Resources');
CefLocalesDirPath:=concat(myworkdir, '\Resources\locales');
```

(Pois o fpcef precisa do caminho INTEIRO para encontrar o binário do CEF, óbviamente você terá que declarar a variável myworkdir como string).

Pronto agora já vai rodar (fora do lazarus, ou seja direto pelo executável) sem esta mensagem.

Comment: Grato! Vou testar aqui e caso funcione marco como correta!

Comment: Funcionou! Inclusive compilando o projeto para uma pasta separada (no caso o projeto estava na src e o executável (com os arquivos do CEF) na bin.

Sugiro editar a resposta e adicionar aquele aviso de nao rodar o programa pelo lazarus usando o f9, tirando isso excelente resposta!
Muito obrigado!

Comment: Ok foi adicionado.